# Create unique id and value properties for each <option> in a drop down of varying size

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm creating a nodejs application using an ejs file as my view. I have a drop down menu created that pulls from a json file to populate it. I want to make it so each option has a unique id or value so i know which option was selected.

I've tried using the ejs tags in to insert it into the tag  properties but it won't be seen inside of an html tag.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
      <select name="charChoice">
              <% for (var k in list.names){ %>
                    <option id="old"><%=list.names[k]%></option>
              <% } %>
          <option value="new">New Character</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Choose">
</form>
```

Here's what I have so far. I want unique id's for the option tag that is currently labeled old.

Comment: Could you provide some example of `list.names`? Why don't you put `k` in `<option value="<%= k %>">...`?

Comment: list is just a javascript object i passed to my ejs file and names is just an array of all names i have. Also i removed the id from the looped option and apperantly it works without it. Does the value attribute default to the option's text?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `list.names` is an Array, store index of each position in option.value:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <select name="charChoice">
        <% for (var k = 0; k < list.names; k++) { %>
            <option value="<%= k %>"><%= list.names[k] %></option>
        <% } %>
        <option value="new">New Character</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Choose">
</form>
```

Server side:

```
myAction = function(req, res) {
    var list = {};
    list.names = myFunctionToLoadNames(); // [ "name1", "name2", etc.. ]

    var charChoice = req.body.charChoice;
    if (charChoice == "new") {
        // ...
    } else {
        var charChoiceSelected = list.names[];
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: <option value="<%= k %>"> is not interpreted in the way you think. From what I've see and tested it interprets the value to be nothing

Answer (score 0):

The option tag defaults it's value attribute to whatever text is given to it, i.e.

```
<option>some text</option>
```

will have "some text" be assigned as it's value. Did some testing with this and it holds up.